# Adding listeners in nodeJS if the listener is not already added and listener handler is an anonymous function

Tags: node.js, event-handling, listener, addeventlistener

Is there a way to check if a listener already exist for an object in node.js?
I want to implement the following scenario:

- Get an object of db
- Do some operation
- Add listeners eg error, result, drain etc if the same listener is not already added [assume that for all the operations the listener operation is same]

I wanted to optimize the addition of listeners in such a way that new listeners wont be added if we try and add an existing listener. Node documentation says  "*No checks are made to see if the listener has already been added. Multiple calls passing the same combination of eventName and listener will result in the listener being added, and called, multiple times.*"

Is there a way around it?
[EDIT]-Adding some sample code

```
 connpool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

      var querystr = "Some valid SQL query";

      connection.execute(querystr, data, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        connection.on('error', function(err){onErr(err,connection);});
        do some stuff
        cleanup(connection);
    });
    })  

   var onErr = function(err, connection) {
      console.error({"Error message"});
      connection.release();
      cleanup(connection);
   };

   var cleanup = function(conn) {
    conn.removeListener('error',onErr);
   };
```

Connection will contain a db connection and its coming from an external package.In the statement  connection.on('error', function(err){onErr(err,connection);}); i'm using an anonymous function as i need to pass an extra argument to the cleanup method. During cleanup i dont get a handler to the function as i'm using an anonymous function.

Comment: Just check the [listeners currently bound to the particular event](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_listeners_eventname) to see if the one you want to add exists. Use `emitter.listeners(eventName)`.

Comment: @CoolBlue: how do i check the name of the listeners being bound by util.inspect? It gives back the output as : "Listeners in add are [ [Function],
  { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
  [Function],
  [Function] ] "

Comment: Just use a reference to the listener function to check against the array of listeners returned by `emitter.listeners(eventName)`.  See answer below...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using an anonymous function  for the listener handler. The events are thrown from a mysql package and they only accept err as an argument. I'll edit the question to include some code

Comment: You could move the `onErr` and `cleanup` functions inside the scope of the `getConnection` callback.  Then you could use the (un-wrapped) `onErr` as the listener, but change it's signature to `onErr(err)` and access `connection` lexically.

Comment: no..there are multiple places where we use the cleanup and onErr in the module. this is just a snippet of the original code.  It would be impractical to duplicate the whole in each callbacks where its used, any other approach??

Comment: OK, that's what I thought... what is `this` when the listener is called?  I would have though it was the connection.  If it is then you don't need the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep a reference to the listener when you hook it, you can check if it is in the array of listeners returned by `emitter.listeners(eventName)`.

Rough example (I'm sure it could be more efficient)

```
/**
 * Created by cool.blue on 8/4/2016.
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/38700859/2670182
 */
const EE = require('events');
const util = require('util');

var host = new EE();

// set up a emitter with n events
const n = 10;
const events = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map((x, i) => 'event_' + i);

events.forEach(function(e){
    host.on(e, function g() {console.log(e)})
});

console.log(util.inspect(host));

// get a reference to one of the listener functions
const target = 'event_3';
var probe = host.listeners(target)[0];

// add a method to only add unique listeners
host.onUnique = function (type, listener){
    var slot = this.listeners(type).find(function(l) {
        return l === listener
    });

    if(slot)
        return this;

    console.log('adding');
    return this.on(type, listener)
};

// try to add the same listener again
var count0 = host.listenerCount(target);
var count1 = host.onUnique(target, probe).listenerCount(target);

console.log('added ' + (count1 - count0) + ' listeners');   // added 0 listeners
console.log(util.inspect(host));

// try to add a new listener
count0 = host.listenerCount(target);
count1 = host.onUnique(target, function h(){ console.log('different cb')}).listenerCount(target);

console.log('added ' + (count1 - count0) + ' listeners');   // added 1 listeners
console.log(util.inspect(host));
```

---

**In response to the updated question...**

you could do something like this...

TL;DR

the basic idea is to use a non-anonymous function for the listener and pass a reference to it and the connection to the utility functions in the outer scope.

```
const EE = require('events');
const util = require('util');

(function manage(host){

    host.name = 'host';
    host.release = function(){
        console.log('released!')
    };

    function l(err) {
        onErr(err, host, l)
    }
    l.e = 'error';

    host.on('error', l);

    if(Math.random() > 0.5)
        host.emit('error', new Error('oops!'));

    if(l.e)
        cleanUp(host, l, 'manage');

})(new EE());

function onErr(e, h, l) {
    console.error(`\n${h.name}: ${e.message}`);
    h.release();
    cleanUp(h, l, 'onError')
}

function cleanUp(h, l, context){
    console.log('\n\x1b[33m' + context + '\n'
        + 'before:\t' + h._eventsCount + '\x1b[0m\n' + util.inspect(h));
    h.removeListener(l.e, l);
    console.log('\n\x1b[33mafter:\t' + h._eventsCount + '\x1b[0m\n' + util.inspect(h));
    delete l.e
}
```

The IIFE is just to simulate your situation where there is no reference to `host` (`connection`) in the outer scope.

Comment: Thankx for your snippets, i made a solution combining both these.and sorry for the delay in response!